# JPAで接続しているデータベースの種類を動的に識別する方法

Tags: java, jpa

JPA(EclipseLink)を使って、SQLServer/Oracle/PostgreSQLのいずれでも利用できるJavaEEアプリケーションを作っています。
その中で、どうしても上記3種を区別して処理を分ける必要が生じました。
どうやったらアプリケーション上から動的に検出できるのか、何か方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: 英語版に同様の質問がありました。
Dialect.getDialect()の結果で判別するといいと思います。 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879649/how-to-detect-database-from-hibernate-user-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

動作確認してませんが、こんな実装で取得した`databaseProductName`で判別できないでしょうか。

```
java.sql.Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
String databaseProductName = connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
```

Answer (score 0):

申し訳ありません、EclipseLinkでしたね。eclipselink.target-databaseプロパティを使用してください。

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#target-database